# Trying to set the current selection of a spinner using a string instead of an index

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to set the selection of a spinner using a string instad of an index. So if I have spinner of red, green and blue, I could set the current selection to blue by using the string "blue" instad of the index 2.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: you could `map` the colors with index and call `Hashmap.get("color");` wouldnt it solve  your requirement ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spinner should be backed by an adapter with an array of strings. You can set the selection of your spinner with a string like so:

`mySpinner.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getPosition("blue"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can get position from adapter by using `adapter.getPosition("your item");`.

And set select by that position..

For example:

```
int mPosition = mAdapter.getPosition("blue");
mSpinner.setSelection(mPosition);
```